# What does it mean 'All mid all random' in League Of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have just started playing League of Legends.

What does it mean the match description 'All mid all random' in game browser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All players should pick a random hero, and everyone should only go into the middle lane.

Comment: What is its purpose?

Comment: @Drake - it's just something you can do for fun, as a change from the normal metagame. It's not supported by matchmaking -- ARAM are done as "practice" matches only.

Comment: Custom Games, rather.

Answer (score 15):

ARAM games are custom games set to the "all random" mode. Your champion is picked for you from the pool of champions you own + champions that are free this week. ARAMs also have some player-enforced rules:

1. You cannot leave mid lane. Do not enter the bushes or the jungle.
2. You cannot travel back to your base to heal unless your mid lane inhibitor is down.
3. You cannot use Recall.
4. You cannot buy items from the shop until you die (because of #2 and #3).
5. You cannot buy Guardian Angel.
6. You cannot buy "snowball" items that stack on player kills: Mejiai's Soulstealer, Sword of the Occult, and Leviathan.

There are also some rules that aren't always enforced but you'll commonly see:

1. The summoner skill Fortify is also banned.
2. You have to give the other team a free kill on you if you break a rule. And you have to sell a banned item if you buy it.

Comment: In reference to your rule #6, what about rengar's bonetooth necklace?

Comment: @Ender This answer is kind of oudated now, because Riot added The Proving Grounds custom map mode. As for casual Summoner's Rift ARAM games: I assume Ragnar's item is allowed because it's custom for him.